# Chained application installation

Tags: visual-studio-2005, setup-deployment

HI,
I am using visual studio for creating a msi file for my application. It checks whether .net 2.0 is present in the system or not. If it is not present the installation aborts.

I need to install .net 2.0 if it is not present and continue with the application installation and not to abort the installation.

How can this be achieved in Visual Studio 2005 Setup and Deployment Projects???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea. Having spent considerable time with the VS Setup project though, I can tell you one thing: they are **terrible**. I mean truly awful. I love VS, but those projects are an embarassment. It's pathetic that they think you can get anywhere with them. I cannot stress enough just how utterly bad they are.

That said, what you should do is switch to [Windows Installer XML](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), usually known as "WiX". It comes with a VS plugin that basically just does some basic linkup, and then you set up the XML as you please. It takes some getting used to, since there's no UI for anything. In the end though, it is such a massive improvement over the VS stuff that it's worth the extra time (like an hour or so) to get acquainted with the format.

Comment: Actually I would like to have a GUI based tool within visual studio 2005 if possible. Is it available with visual studio 2008??